# Ignore code between two C++ macros (prevent creating static unittest objects)

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

```
// in someFile.h or someFile.cpp
TEST()
{
    "example test", []
    {
         EXPECT(0 == 1);
    }
}
TEST_END()

// in main.cpp
int main() { ssvu::Test::runAllTests(); }
```

---

```
#define TEST() static RunOnCtor UNIQUENAME(__LINE__) { []{ getStaticTests().push_back({
#define TEST_END() });}};
struct RunOnCtor { RunOnCtor(std::function<void()> f) { f(); } };
```

---

I've created some unit testing macros that work both in header (useful for my header-only libraries) and source files.

`TEST()` creates a static instance of `RunOnCtor`, which, on construction, executes a lambda  which inserts the *test lambda* into a `std::vector` of tests. `runAllTests()` runs every test in that vector.

I have created a `DISABLE_TEST` define that simply puts `return;` at the beginning of the `RunOnCtor` lambda, so that no tests are added to the internal vector. However, I would like to prevent unnecessary construction of static objects when tests are disabled.

Is there a way to completely ignore everything between `TEST()` and `TEST_END()`? Something like commenting it out. Or would emptying out `RunOnCtor` (empty struct) make the compiler avoid static constructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
#define TEST() struct UNIQUENAME(__LINE__) { void f() {

#define TEST_END() } };
```

Comment: And the compiler should completely get rid of the `UNIQUENAME(__LINE__) struct` code and `f()`, correct?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo This code doesn't define any variables or call any functions, so nothing will be executed at runtime. It's possible the linker will remove the code of `f()` from the final binary because it has no callers. But even if it doesn't, you're only facing larger binary size, not any runtime cost.

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on @Angew 's answer but uses standard preprocessor definitions. The class then defines a function within the class declaration, which in C++ forces it to be inline. Because the class is never instantiated and the function is never called, no code is ever generated.

```
#define CAT(a, ...) PCAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PCAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
#define TEST() class CAT(Obfuscate_, __LINE__) { void f() {
#define TEST_END() } };

int c;
TEST()
    int a = 7;
    int b = a * 17;
    c = b + 4;
    return;
TEST_END()
```

Here's Godbolt's handy-dandy compiler explorer to prove that GCC, CLANG, and ICC produce no code for the above: https://godbolt.org/g/BXKDNF